# What is the bios settings I have to use to recognise my seagate hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I have installed the windows OS on my hard disk. But somehow, it does not recognise the seagate hard disk, in the existing bios mode settings, that is enhanced settings, enabling both sata and pata to be enabled.

I am not tech savvy, that this enhanced mode was selected by technician to work with the new hard drive by WD.

In present settings, seagate hard drive if connected would not go past POST. it remains in mother board logo. I think that the same hard disk was working when I was working with the seagate drive.

What should I do to recognise the old hard drive which was checked and found to have no problem at all.

I tested cmos clearing, shorting of cmos circuits , but nothing happens. I tried other fixes. I do not know, if i have to choose the legacy settings. My hard drive is connected with ribbon like ide cable and a power cable.The same thing is used with the present hard drive.

I could not format the drive, in my computer, as the seagate drive does not go past POST to be recognised.But the same thing could be seem to have worked with connecting the same to other computers. Would you say some solution to this problem.

Should I format the drive in other computer and then install the OS. Will it work. Or shoudl I choose some menu in the latest bios for my model. My model is d915 gav intel mother board. the legacy menu, include in drive configuation legacy ide channels, sata p0/p2,p1/p3,sata p1/p3,pata,sata p0/p2,pata, and pata only are the options in the drive configurations.